# Date to epoch and vice versa - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert date to Java epoch and then read it and convert back. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

```
var date = new Date('1/3/2013');
var timeStamp = date.getTime();
console.log(timeStamp);
var revertDate = new Date(timeStamp);
console.log(revertDate.getDate()+'/'+revertDate.getMonth()+'/'+revertDate.getFullYear());
```

The output is `3/0/2013` instad `1/3/2013`?

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/EHZXm/)

Comment: What is the output and what was you expecting?

Comment: @EdHeal: As per the end of the question: "The output is 3/0/2013 instad 1/3/2013?"

Comment: It's not clear to me how this is particularly about jquery, by the way...

Comment: @JonSkeet, the solutions are acceptable in jquery.

Comment: @RuntimeException: It's not clear what "solution" you're looking for - the conversion from `Date` to milliseconds-since-the-epoch and back is working fine; it's your parsing and formatting that are causing you problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two problems here:

- The `Date` constructor is assuming `M/d/yyyy` format - whereas you're logging `d/M/yyyy` format. Personally I'd suggest using an ISO-8601 format if at all possible: `yyyy-MM-dd`
- You're not taking into account the fact that `getMonth()` returns a 0-based value

For the formatting side, you'd be better off using `toISOString` or something similar, rather than doing the formatting yourself.

(Note that looking at the [documentation for the `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) it's not clear that the code you've got should work at all, as it's neither an RFC822 nor ISO-8601 format.)

Neither of the problems are to do with converting between `Date` and a numeric value. If you change your logging, you'll see that clearly:

```
var date = new Date('1/3/2013');
var timeStamp = date.getTime();
console.log(date);
var revertDate = new Date(timeStamp);
console.log(revertDate);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, do you see any issues if I parse date like this 'revertDate.getMonth()+1+'/'+revertDate.getDate()+'/'+revertDate.getFullYear())'? or Are you able to provide me a quick example with formatting please?

Comment: @RuntimeException: I would use `toISOString` instead; there's no ambiguity there.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date('1/3/2013');
```

The `Date` constructor is parsing this given string this way:

> **Month** / **Day** / **Year**

So, in this case, Month is 1, Day is 3 and Year is 2013. What's going on there? Well that's quite simple. This Gregorian representation of a date(which is specifically **Day** / **Month** / **Year** ) isn't the one used by the Date constructor, so it will parse the `1`(the month) as January, the `3` as the third day of the month(the third of Jan) and the year correctly, the 2013. Now, due to its 0-based indexing, the constructed `Date` object will return a month which is `n-1` among the one provided. That's why you're getting `3/0/2013`. It is the third day(3) of the month 0(which is January) of 2013. If you want to get your real date you have to do this:

```
var date = new Date('3/1/2013');
console.log(date.getDate()+'/'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: What if the date format is Day/Month/Year e.g. 22/07/2013? How do I deal with this?

Comment: If passed to the Date constructor it will be parsed correctly. 22nd of July, 2013.

Comment: Could you please provide me a working example with this format '22/07/2013'?

Comment: `var dateSplit = '22/07/2013'.split('/')` <-- produces an array of three elements containing 22, 07 and 2013. Now pass it to the Date constructor, which accepts even three elements(see the reference passed by @JonSkeet), in order they are year, month and day, so you'll just need to do `var date = new Date(dateSplit[2], dateSplit[1] - 1, dateSplit[0]);` and you're done.